# How to represent date format in '2015120' in Linux shell?

Tags: bash, command-line, date

My colleague is generating log files with a preceding date format like `2015120`, which represent January as `1` instead of `01`.

The usual way I'm using to deal with this kind of issue is using `date` command.Like `date +'%Y%m%d'`. But I maned date command, it turns out they didn't mention represent January without a preceding 0.

So I'm wondering is there an another way to represent date like  `2015120` in Linux?

Comment: ...what a bad idea ;-). So, a a glance,  `2015112` is November, 2nd or January, 12th?

Comment: @Rmano, Yes, it's a bad idea, but I can't decide that. By the way November 2nd will be represent as 20151102 at his strategy.

Comment: You should get a better colleague. This is, simply put, a STUPID way of writing dates. Did you ask him why he did this? I suspect he simply didn't think of padding the month.

Comment: But you save ONE byte for almost every date! That's 1GB for every 1073741824 log files! </sarcasm>

Comment: I would suggest that you and your colleage join efforts to migrate to a better date scheme. The whole purpose of prepending dates is to automatically get date ordering, but it doesn't help if Jan 31 (`2015131`) > Oct 1 (`20151001`).

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: Any answer that doesn't start with you bodily assaulting your colleague with a fish (your choice) for choosing such an obviously idiotic date format is sub-par. **Fix the date format; fix the problem. Do not implement this datespec.** It *will* bite you in the arse before the year is over.

Comment: out of curiousity, does he zero pad days? Is Feb 1st written as 201521 or 2015201?

Comment: I would read 2015112 as year 2015, day 112.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It's funny how that xkcd lists 20130227 as a discouraged format, when it's in fact also defined by ISO 8601. (Of course, using hyphens is preferable if humans are going to read the date.)

Comment: @Rmano, I was wrong, it turns out he also omit the padding for days. What a disaster, I'm going to fix that.

Comment: So you didn't read the manpage all the way through.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, when at busy work, normally you'll scan the man-page, or search with particular key-words.

Comment: @Zen: No, you'll read it _thoroughly_ and gain an _understanding_. You cannot possibly be a diligent developer and get stuff done if you give up after a search for particular keywords turns up nothing useful. _READ_.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With GNU, FreeBSD or OS/X `date` (or `date` implementations that use the system's `libc`'s `strftime()` where that is the GNU `libc`), adding hyphen `-` after `%` prevents numeric fields from being padded with zeroes:

```
$ date +'%Y%-m%d'
2015120
```

From [man date](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) on a GNU system:

> By default, date  pads  numeric  fields  with  zeroes. The following
>   optional flags may follow `%':
>
> -      (hyphen) do not pad the field

If your system `date` does not support that, you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -e '
  $t = localtime;
  print $t->year, $t->mon, $t->mday;
'
2015122
```

Comment: I'd add a nice `# ... but you do NOT want that!` comment on the same line

Answer (score 6):

```
> date +'%Y %m %d' | ( read year month day; echo "${year}${month#0}${day}" )
2015120
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add a one (1) after the hyphen (-) it works on Linux and is also portable to [HP-UX](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1/date.1.html) (and possibly other flavors of UNIX):

```
$ date +'%Y%-1m%d'
2015120
```

Comment: Note that it's independent from the kernel, so "Linux" has no bearing here. ITYM it works on _GNU_ and HP/UX. However note that contrary to `date +%-m`, it doesn't work on FreeBSD or OS/X.